# How do I do a ggplot and use different bars for different years

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that includes the number of countries in each region per year in a data set.
I have used the below code to plot a bar chart but I would like it to plot the numbers for each year but not sure how.

```
region_year <- data_na_removed%>%
 group_by(Region, Year)%>%
 summarise(Number = n())%>%
 arrange(desc(Number))

region_year%>%
 ggplot() +
 geom_col(aes(x = Region, y = Number), fill='lightblue') +
 labs(title = 'The Number of countries in each Region in 2014') +
 ylab('Number') + xlab('Region')
```

'''

Comment: You could try with `geom_col(aes(x = Region, y = Number, fill = factor(Year)), position = "dodge")` to show the different years via a dodged bar chart or another option would be to use facettting `+ facet_wrap(~Year)`.

Comment: Its not liking factor(Year) it says it can't find Year

Comment: Hm. According to your code snippet there should be a column `Year` run your dataset `region_year`. So check that this is indeed the case. If you need more help then please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. If you want to post your data type `dput(region_year)` into the console and copy the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.

Comment: There is defiantly a column called Year.

Comment: Im not sure how to copy the data into the question

Comment: Copy the "weird" looking output from your console as an edit into your post. And good practice would be to format is as code.

Comment: I have managed to sort it so it is one column with the multiple colours in but was aiming to have each year next to each other

Comment: By default ´geom_col` will give you a stacked barchart. To change that use `geom_col(..., position = "dodge")`. That will you a dodged barchart with bars for the years placed side by side for each region

Answer (score 0):

What you want is facets, e.g. http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/

simply add `+ facet_wrap(vars(Year))`

Comment: Not liking this either